# Embedding whole flat 2-Torus in $\Bbb R^3$

Tags: differential-geometry, metric-spaces, riemannian-geometry

I am trying to better understand an isometric embedding of a flat 2-Torus in $\Bbb R^3$ via a $C^1$ map. Here is a visualization involving $C^1$ fractals:

[image]

This embedding is warped by an infinite sequence of waves called corrugations, according to the [Hévéa Project](http://hevea-project.fr/ENPageToreDossierDePresse.html) (thanks to @dvitek for the reference). Due to this infinity, it is unclear how the points of this surface can be defined.

My question is if this surface can be described as a function of the $x,y,z$ coordinates in $\Bbb R^3$ either in the explicit or parametric way.

Comment: You should specify what you mean by "explicit" and keep in mind that it cannot be a $C^2$-smooth map. All known constructions are limits of sequences of explicit maps.

Comment: @MoisheKohan By "explicit" I mean that for any given $x$ and $y$, I can use a known procedure to calculate the existence and values of $z$ on the surface.

Comment: This is still unclear: What do you mean by a "known procedure" and "to calculate?" For instance, the construction of Nash-Kuiper embeddings is a known, albeit infinite, process, involving taking a limit of a sequence of recursively defined maps. This is how they produce computer-generated pictures (but stop after few steps). Do you regard this as "known?" If not, you are out of luck.

Comment: @MoisheKohan This is helpful, thank you! Can we say that for any $(x,y)$ the number of values of $z$ is known? Or does it change as we increase the precision?

Comment: None of the value are known precisely but the precision improves with the number of iterations.